# What is this weird dark "blooming" around this object?

Tags: rendering, shadows

I have two separate files-- making a few maps. The lettering are all separate objects sunk into the map mesh.

[image: This one looks good.]

I copied and pasted the objects into the new map. But as you can see, they throw off different shadows. The one I pasted into has lots of noise and looks like it's "blooming" shadows. I have the same world settings and the map mesh is the same too. I can't figure this out. Halp. I'm rendering in cycles and on a MacBook Pro.

[image: This is the problem map]

Comment: the second one looks like a harsh ambient occlusion. Is this a render or the viewport? Which render engine ?

Comment: It’s a screengrab of the cycles render view. But when I render it,  it looks just like it. Can I turn off ambient occlusion. Tbh I’m a Blender n00b.

Comment: Could you pack your external data in your file, save as a compressed copy, upload somewhere like [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can check ourselves?

Comment: You were right. I had an ambient occlusion node hooked up (incorrectly) to bring out the detail in the map mesh. That screwed with the objects placed over the mesh. Thanks!